Replace all nan in a 2D array by the nanmean() value of adjacent neighboring cells
I have a 2D array witch include some nan and I would like do the following :

replace each nan in the array by the nanmean() value of adjacent neighboring cells.
if the neighboring cells are all nan, then the value is nan
if there are some nan in the neighboring cells then the value is the nanmean() value of adjacent neighboring cells.
Let's take some examples :

a = np.random.randint(0,100,60).astype(float)
a = a.reshape(6,10) 
a[1,1]= np.nan
a[2:5,4:7]=np.nan
a
array([[48., 84., 80., 59., 43., 60., 31., 37.,  4., 75.],
       [83., nan, 52., 34., 95., 15., 69.,  7.,  7., 16.],
       [10.,  6.,  6., 44., nan, nan, nan, 95., 28.,  4.],
       [12.,  1., 62., 96., nan, nan, nan, 66., 21., 80.],
       [41., 18.,  1., 49., nan, nan, nan, 27., 64., nan],
       [13., 33., 98., 85., 77., 20., 73., 57., 15., 28.]])

# In this array a[1,1] is a nan and should be replaced by 46.125
np.nanmean(np.array([48.,84.,80.,52.,6.,6.,10.,83.]))
46.125

# Another example a[2,4] is a nan and should be replaced by 56.8
np.nanmean(np.array([34.,95.,15.,44.,96.]))
56.8

etc.


So far I have tried the following techniques :

Using some loop : very easy but very slow if the array is big (1000 x 1000)
Scipy NearestNDInterpolator, interesting but replace all nan (nans surrounded by nans must remain nans!)

How to do this in the fastest way, without looping ?

Use a 2D convolution (scipy.signal.convolve2d):
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

m = np.isnan(a)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3))

# sum of values
S1 = convolve2d(np.nan_to_num(a), kernel, mode='same')
# count of non-NaNs
S2 = convolve2d(~m, kernel, mode='same')

# optional: update the mask to ensure excluding cells
# fully surrounded with NaNs:
m &= S2!=0

# replace NaNs with mean (sum/count)
a[m] = S1[m]/S2[m]

Updated a:
array([[48.  , 84.  , 80.  , 59.  , 43.  , 60.  , 31.  , 37.  ,  4.  , 75.  ],
       [83.  , 46.12, 52.  , 34.  , 95.  , 15.  , 69.  ,  7.  ,  7.  , 16.  ],
       [10.  ,  6.  ,  6.  , 44.  , 56.8 , 59.67, 50.4 , 95.  , 28.  ,  4.  ],
       [12.  ,  1.  , 62.  , 96.  , 63.  ,   nan, 62.67, 66.  , 21.  , 80.  ],
       [41.  , 18.  ,  1.  , 49.  , 65.4 , 56.67, 48.6 , 27.  , 64.  , 41.6 ],
       [13.  , 33.  , 98.  , 85.  , 77.  , 20.  , 73.  , 57.  , 15.  , 28.  ]])

Intermediates:
# m
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])

# S1
array([[215., 347., 309., 363., 306., 313., 219., 155., 146., 102.],
       [231., 369., 365., 413., 350., 313., 314., 278., 273., 134.],
       [112., 232., 301., 389., 284., 179., 252., 293., 324., 156.],
       [ 88., 157., 283., 258., 189.,   0., 188., 301., 385., 197.],
       [118., 279., 443., 468., 327., 170., 243., 323., 358., 208.],
       [105., 204., 284., 310., 231., 170., 177., 236., 191., 107.]])

# S2
array([[3., 5., 5., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 4.],
       [5., 8., 8., 8., 7., 6., 7., 8., 9., 6.],
       [5., 8., 8., 7., 5., 3., 5., 7., 9., 6.],
       [6., 9., 9., 6., 3., 0., 3., 6., 8., 5.],
       [6., 9., 9., 7., 5., 3., 5., 7., 8., 5.],
       [4., 6., 6., 5., 4., 3., 4., 5., 5., 3.]])


Thanks, but nans surrounded by nans must remain nans.
a[3,5] is nan and should remain nan

@Styx I copied the wrong output; a[3, 5] will remain nan. Give it a try ;)

Nevertheless, I updated the approach to explicitly do that

Wow that's very well done and it seems to work as intended! Give me some time to check the performance with a large array. Thank you so much.

performances are very impressive. For an array of 1,038,961 values with 361,428 nan it take around 0,085 sec ! This is the best performance I have got so far.

@Styx glad it worked well for you, and thanks for the feedback with the timings.

Note that if the size of the NaN region get really big, there are better method (this problem is generally called "inpainting" and there are functions in packages like OpenCV to do that relatively efficiently). For your provided use-case, a (small) convolution is perfectly fine.

If NaNs are evenly distributed and you want to avoid edge effects: Use 'reflect'.
If NaNs are concentrated at the edges and you want a conservative estimate:
Use 'constant' with cval=0.
If NaNs are few and you prioritize using actual data: Use 'nearest'
Here the script replaces NaNs with the mean of the column and then applies a rolling mean using the reflect mode in the convolve function from SciPy, is preffered. This approach ensures that the edges are handled smoothly and naturally, which is desirable in real-world data processing scenarios.
In short,if we are dealing with NaNs and aiming to replace them with a meaningful value that maintains the data’s integrity, 'reflect' is generally a safe and effective choice.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Sample DataFrame with NaN values
data = np.array([
    [48., 84., 80., 59., 43., 60., 31., 37.,  4., 75.],
    [83., np.nan, 52., 34., 95., 15., 69.,  7.,  7., 16.],
    [10.,  6.,  6., 44., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 95., 28.,  4.],
    [12.,  1., 62., 96., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 66., 21., 80.],
    [41., 18.,  1., 49., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 27., 64., np.nan],
    [13., 33., 98., 85., 77., 20., 73., 57., 15., 28.]
])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f'col_{i+1}' for i in range(data.shape[1])])

# Function to impute NaNs using SimpleImputer and then calculate rolling mean using convolve
def rolling_mean_with_imputer_convolve(x, window, mode='reflect'):
    # Replace NaNs with column mean using sklearn's SimpleImputer
    imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
    x_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1, 1)).flatten()
    
    # Define a kernel for the rolling mean
    kernel = np.ones(window) / window
    
    # Calculate rolling mean using convolve
    rolling_means = convolve(x_imputed, kernel, mode=mode)
    
    return rolling_means

# Apply rolling mean calculation using imputer and convolve for each column
rolling_means_reflect = df.apply(lambda x: rolling_mean_with_imputer_convolve(x, 3, mode='reflect'), axis=0)
rolling_means_constant = df.apply(lambda x: rolling_mean_with_imputer_convolve(x, 3, mode='constant'), axis=0)
rolling_means_nearest = df.apply(lambda x: rolling_mean_with_imputer_convolve(x, 3, mode='nearest'), axis=0)

print("\nCalculated Rolling Means using sklearn for NaN Handling and SciPy convolve (mode='reflect'):")
print(rolling_means_reflect.to_string())

print("\nCalculated Rolling Means using sklearn for NaN Handling and SciPy convolve (mode='constant'):")
print(rolling_means_constant.to_string())

print("\nCalculated Rolling Means using sklearn for NaN Handling and SciPy convolve (mode='nearest'):")
print(rolling_means_nearest.to_string())
'''

Calculated Rolling Means using sklearn for NaN Handling and SciPy convolve (mode='reflect'):
       col_1      col_2      col_3      col_4      col_5      col_6      col_7      col_8      col_9     col_10
0  59.666667  65.466667  70.666667  50.666667  60.333333  45.000000  43.666667  27.000000   5.000000  55.333333
1  47.000000  39.466667  46.000000  45.666667  69.888889  35.555556  52.555556  46.333333  13.000000  31.666667
2  35.000000  11.800000  40.000000  58.000000  79.444444  26.111111  61.444444  56.000000  18.666667  33.333333
3  21.000000   8.333333  23.000000  63.000000  71.666667  31.666667  57.666667  62.666667  37.666667  41.533333
4  22.000000  17.333333  53.666667  76.666667  73.444444  27.777778  62.777778  50.000000  33.333333  49.533333
5  22.333333  28.000000  65.666667  73.000000  75.222222  23.888889  67.888889  47.000000  31.333333  32.200000

Calculated Rolling Means using sklearn for NaN Handling and SciPy convolve (mode='constant'):
       col_1      col_2      col_3      col_4      col_5      col_6      col_7      col_8      col_9     col_10
0  43.666667  37.466667  44.000000  31.000000  46.000000  25.000000  33.333333  14.666667   3.666667  30.333333
1  47.000000  39.466667  46.000000  45.666667  69.888889  35.555556  52.555556  46.333333  13.000000  31.666667
2  35.000000  11.800000  40.000000  58.000000  79.444444  26.111111  61.444444  56.000000  18.666667  33.333333
3  21.000000   8.333333  23.000000  63.000000  71.666667  31.666667  57.666667  62.666667  37.666667  41.533333
4  22.000000  17.333333  53.666667  76.666667  73.444444  27.777778  62.777778  50.000000  33.333333  49.533333
5  18.000000  17.000000  33.000000  44.666667  49.555556  17.222222  43.555556  28.000000  26.333333  22.866667

Calculated Rolling Means using sklearn for NaN Handling and SciPy convolve (mode='nearest'):
       col_1      col_2      col_3      col_4      col_5      col_6      col_7      col_8      col_9     col_10
0  59.666667  65.466667  70.666667  50.666667  60.333333  45.000000  43.666667  27.000000   5.000000  55.333333
1  47.000000  39.466667  46.000000  45.666667  69.888889  35.555556  52.555556  46.333333  13.000000  31.666667
2  35.000000  11.800000  40.000000  58.000000  79.444444  26.111111  61.444444  56.000000  18.666667  33.333333
3  21.000000   8.333333  23.000000  63.000000  71.666667  31.666667  57.666667  62.666667  37.666667  41.533333
4  22.000000  17.333333  53.666667  76.666667  73.444444  27.777778  62.777778  50.000000  33.333333  49.533333
5  22.333333  28.000000  65.666667  73.000000  75.222222  23.888889  67.888889  47.000000  31.333333  32.200000

'''

Now let's Solve the actual question using 3x3 kernel:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer


data = np.array([
    [48., 84., 80., 59., 43., 60., 31., 37.,  4., 75.],
    [83., np.nan, 52., 34., 95., 15., 69.,  7.,  7., 16.],
    [10.,  6.,  6., 44., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 95., 28.,  4.],
    [12.,  1., 62., 96., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 66., 21., 80.],
    [41., 18.,  1., 49., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 27., 64., np.nan],
    [13., 33., 98., 85., 77., 20., 73., 57., 15., 28.]
])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[f'col_{i+1}' for i in range(data.shape[1])])

imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'mean')
df_imputed_values = imputer.fit_transform(df.values)

# Define a 3x3 kernel
kernel = np.ones((3,3))
# 2D convolution 
convolved_data  = convolve(df_imputed_values,kernel,mode='reflect')

# Normalize the convolved values to get the average
normalized_data = convolved_data / kernel.sum()

df_convolved = pd.DataFrame(normalized_data,columns = df.columns)
print(df_convolved.to_string() )
'''
       col_1      col_2      col_3      col_4      col_5      col_6      col_7      col_8      col_9     col_10
0  61.600000  65.266667  62.266667  60.555556  52.000000  49.666667  38.555556  25.222222  29.111111  38.555556
1  44.488889  44.155556  43.711111  53.851852  50.370370  52.666667  44.814815  37.296296  30.333333  25.444444
2  27.266667  28.933333  36.600000  59.148148  54.518519  55.666667  47.851852  45.370370  36.000000  28.444444
3  16.777778  17.444444  31.444444  52.555556  55.444444  53.666667  50.666667  52.666667  47.288889  40.244444
4  20.444444  31.000000  49.222222  67.925926  59.296296  54.666667  46.851852  48.703704  44.288889  44.133333
5  24.222222  38.666667  55.555556  71.296296  57.370370  55.666667  46.259259  48.740741  36.844444  31.911111
'''

 

